# Removing Content Between Multiple Strings

Tags: python, regex

Say hello to String S,

```
s = "X Hello C there. I am B a String. Y I C am a A good string."
```

What I want to do:

- Remove Content from X to C. (Done.)
- Remove Content from C to B or A. (Note how C is repeated twice.)

Now, I'm able to remove the content from X to C using:

```
re.sub('X.*?C','', s, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

How do I go around removing C to B/Y/A?
Would I need to iterate over a list or would regex be able to do it?

#### Expected output: (Need to remove these)

- " there. I am a " (1st C to B)
- " am a " (2nd C to A)

Comment: What's your expected output in the example above?

Comment: Maybe using 1 regex `'X.*?C.*?(?:B|Y|A)'`?

Comment: @MarounMaroun, I've updated the question. Have a look.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I need to remove the C to B/Y/A first before I remove X to Cs.

Comment: No, it makes no sense. You won't be able to do that after you remove a text you would like to find during the subsequent iteration.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Alright I figured out a way to do that- I'm sorry I wasn't clear. I need to keep the text. For example: I'm able to use your exp to remove the contents from C to B/Y/A but I need to keep B/Y/A. Ergo just removing contents from C to 1 index before B/Y/A is. How'd I do that?

Comment: Like https://regex101.com/r/hMmjmF/1? Also, is `B`, `Y` and `A` single chars? Whole words?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, perfect! Thanks. And no they are words. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, that means my regex should work for you, I will post then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, please do. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove text from `X` till the first occurrence of `C` and then any text up to the first occurrence of `B` or `Y` or `A` (keeping them in the resulting string), you may use

```
X.*?C.*?(B|Y|A)
```

and replace with `\1` backreference. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hMmjmF/1). To match across lines, use `re.DOTALL` flag to make `.` match line break chars.

**Details**:

- `X` - matches `X`
- `.*?` -  lazily matches any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first...
- `C`  - `C`
- `.*?` - lazily matches any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first...
- `(B|Y|A)`  - (Group 1) either `B`, `Y`, or `A`.

The `\1` backreference will put back the value inside Group 1.

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/810RC6) (pay attention at the raw string literal when defining the replacement pattern with the backreference):

```
import re
rx = r"X.*?C.*?(B|Y|A)"
s = "X Hello C there. I am B a String. Y I C am a A good string."
print(re.sub(rx, r"\1", s))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.